# How to properly POST data from Android App to PHP?

Tags: php, android, post, retrofit

I'm developing an app that has to post user data to database (login,password,id of device, latitude and longitude). I'm trying to POST it through PHP, but i get eror **"End of input at line 1 column 1 path $"**.

I'm not sure what should I do.

I was trying to do something with gson, but it didn't work also. If anyone has any idea, please let me know... :)

Here is my MainActivity Code:

```
public void createPost(String loginStr, String passwordStr, String id_urzadzenia, double latitude, double longitude) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://unpreached-courtesy.000webhostapp.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    API ApiPlaceHolder = retrofit.create(API.class);

    Call<Post> call = ApiPlaceHolder
            .createPost(
                    loginStr,
                    passwordStr,
                    id_urzadzenia,
                    latitude,
                    longitude);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Code " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, call.request().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

API Interface code:

```
public interface API {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/dane.php")
        Call<Post> createPost (
                @Field("loginStr")String loginStr,
                @Field("passwordStr") String passwordStr,
                @Field("id_urzadzenia") String id_urzadzenia,
                @Field("latitude") double latitude,
                @Field("longitude") double longitude
                );
}
```

Post.java class code:

```
public class Post {
    private String loginStr;

    private String passwordStr;

    private String id_urzadzenia;

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public String getLoginStr() {
        return loginStr;
    }

    public void setLoginStr(String loginStr) {
        this.loginStr = loginStr;
    }

    public String getPasswordStr() {
        return passwordStr;
    }

    public void setPasswordStr(String passwordStr) {
        this.passwordStr = passwordStr;
    }

    public String getId_urzadzenia() {
        return id_urzadzenia;
    }

    public void setId_urzadzenia(String id_urzadzenia) {
        this.id_urzadzenia = id_urzadzenia;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

And there is my PHP:

```
    <?php header('Content-Type: application/json');



$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


$login = $_POST["loginStr"];
$id_urz = $_POST["id_urzadzenia"];
$dl_geo = $_POST["longitude"];
$sz_geo = $_POST["latitude"];
echo "Login użytkownika: " .$login . "\n";
echo "ID urządzenia: " . $id_urz . "\n";
echo "Szerokość geograficzna: " . $sz_geo . "\n";
echo "Długość geograficzna: " . $dl_geo . "\n";
date_default_timezone_get(Europe);
$godz =  date("H:i:s");
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE bartek (id_urzadzenia,szerokosc,dlugosc,data) VALUES ('".json_encode($id_urz)."','".json_encode($sz_geo)."','".json_encode($dl_geo)."','".$godz."'";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

in Gradle

```
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

in Interface eg: make RetrofitAPI.java

```
        public static PostService postService = null;

        public static PostService getService() {
          if (postService == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_url)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
            postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);

           }
          return postService;
        }
        public interface API {
            @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST
            Call<Post> createPost(@Url String url,
                                       @Field("id_urzadzenia") String id_urzadzenia,
                    @Field("loginStr") String loginStr,
                    @Field("passwordStr") String passwordStr,
                    @Field("longitude") String longitude,
                    @Field("latitude") String latitude
                                       );
        }
```

in MainActivity

```
public void createPost(String loginStr, String passwordStr, String id_urzadzenia, double latitude, double longitude) throws IOException {
     final Call<Post> call_api = RetrofitAPI.getService().createPost(url, id_urzadzenia, loginStr, passwordStr, longitude, latitude );
            call_api.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                        if(response.body() != null){

                            // Toast.makeText(ACTIVITY.this, "Success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                        // Toast.makeText(ACTIVITY.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });
            }

}
```

Change your php file like this. now it should insert into your database

```
//your database configuration

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


$login = $_POST["loginStr"];
$id_urz = $_POST["id_urzadzenia"];
$dl_geo = $_POST["longitude"];
$sz_geo = $_POST["latitude"];
// echo "Login użytkownika: " .$login . "\n";
// echo "ID urządzenia: " . $id_urz . "\n";
// echo "Szerokość geograficzna: " . $sz_geo . "\n";
// echo "Długość geograficzna: " . $dl_geo . "\n";
date_default_timezone_get(Europe);
$godz =  date("H:i:s");
$sql = "INSERT INTO bartek (id_urzadzenia,szerokosc,dlugosc,data) VALUES ('$id_urz','$sz_geo','$dl_geo','$godz')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So, the server gets the POST request, and its returning the results with echo, but app says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2". Here is the servers answer: https://imgur.com/a/KoRI4P3

Comment: Although, the values aren't shown on the website... Only in Android Studio.

Comment: It's probably something with my php file, I'm just using somethin like "$value = $_POST["value"]; Don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: your response is in string change it to object. Can you share how you response back from the php.

Comment: write ````header('Content-Type: application/json');```` in top of your php file and use 
````echo json_encode($data);```` where data is your response object.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Now I'm getting error "End of input at line 1 column 1 path $" :(

Comment: if your table name is ````bartek```` then write  ````INSERT INTO bartek```` check whether the data is inserting into database or not

Comment: No, Its not, but I'm no longer getting error " End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ ". I edited my API like that:
    Call<Void> createPost

Comment: It's working, finally. But now I want to create a Table named like my $id_urz, and then insert values in it. Do You know how to do that? By the way, thank You very much for your help.